# how can I get ALL records from route53?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

how can I get ALL records from route53?

referring code snippet here, which seemed to work for someone, however not clear to me: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/620

Trying to get all (I have about ~7000 records) via resource record sets but can't seem to get the pagination to work with `list_resource_record_sets`. Here's what I have:

```
route53 = Aws::Route53::Client.new
response = route53.list_resource_record_sets({ 
  start_record_name: fqdn(name),
  start_record_type: type,
  max_items: 100, # fyi - aws api maximum is 100 so we'll need to page 
}) 

response.last_page? 
response = response.next_page until response.last_page?
```

I verified I'm hooked into right region, I see the record I'm trying to get (so I can delete later) in aws console, but can't seem to get it through the api. I used this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/620 as a starting point.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or is there an easier way, perhaps another method in the api I'm not finding, for me to get just the record I need given the hosted_zone_id, type and name?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you linked is for the Ruby AWS SDK v2, but the latest is v3. It also looks like things may have changed around a bit since 2014, as I'm not seeing the `#next_page` or `#last_page?` methods in the [v2 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_resource_record_sets-instance_method) or the [v3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_resource_record_sets-instance_method).

Consider using the `#next_record_name` and `#next_record_type` from the response when `#is_truncated` is true. That's more consistent with how other paginations work in the Ruby AWS SDK, such as with DynamoDB scans for example.

Something like the following should work (though I don't have an AWS account with records to test it out):

```
route53 = Aws::Route53::Client.new

hosted_zone = ? # Required field according to the API docs
next_name = fqdn(name)
next_type = type

loop do
  response = route53.list_resource_record_sets(
    hosted_zone_id: hosted_zone,
    start_record_name: next_name,
    start_record_type: next_type,
    max_items: 100, # fyi - aws api maximum is 100 so we'll need to page 
  )

  records = response.resource_record_sets

  # Break here if you find the record you want

  # Also break if we've run out of pages
  break unless response.is_truncated

  next_name = response.next_record_name
  next_type = response.next_record_type
end
```

Comment: groovy I see what's going on now. break if response.last_page? seems to be working the dependencies I already have set up. I'll accept once I confirm (doing so now).